# What does the "d" mean after linux packages?

Tags: linux, packages, ubuntu

I've noticed that a lot of the packages I've been installing on my Ubuntu machine has this "d" at the end.  Googling it doesn't give me any answers that I can find.

For example:

FTP server - 
Package called: pure-ftpd

TFTP server - 
Package called: atftpd

SSH server - 
Package called: sshd

What's up with this "d"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that is not a subjective question about programming.

Comment: @user16764 per my reading of [about] page, being _subjective_ is not a mandatory requirement for the question to be on-topic: "*conceptual* questions..."

Comment: It belongs to askubuntu SE o Unix-Linux SE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`d` is for `demon` or [`daemon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) in this case.

Those packages are the background processes that handle the various connections (FTP, TFTP, SSH) mentioned.

As a hint, the name of the package ("*_*_ server") indicates you're likely going to need a background process running to provide that service.

---

And here's the Wikipedia quote on [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)

> In multitasking computer operating systems, a daemon (/ˈdeɪmən/ or /ˈdiːmən/)[1] is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user. Traditionally daemon names end with the letter d: for example, syslogd is the daemon that implements the system logging facility and sshd is a daemon that services incoming SSH connections.

Comment: It should be noted, that the actual binaries also have this `d` in their name.

Comment: @JanHudec - that's a good point. The packages often reflect the name of the primary binary that would be used.

Answer (score 4):

[**Daemon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29):

> In multitasking computer operating systems, a daemon (/ˈdeɪmən/ or
>   /ˈdiːmən/) is a computer program that runs as a background process,
>   rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user.
>   Traditionally daemon names end with the letter d: for example, syslogd
>   is the daemon that implements the system logging facility and sshd is
>   a daemon that services incoming SSH connections.
>
> [...]
>
> The term was coined by the programmers of MIT's Project MAC. They took the name from Maxwell's demon, an imaginary being from a famous thought experiment that constantly works in the background, sorting molecules.